# Nexus 4 sync contacts

Tags: ubuntu-touch, 15.04, android, sync, nexus-4

I am trying to sync my contacts between a Nexus 4 Ubuntu phone (15.04 OTA 12) and an Android phone. I can import a vcf file from the android, but end up with duplicate contacts and there seems to be no way to merge these on ubuntu, and I cannot find a way to export to a vcf file from ubuntu and use Android to merge the contacts. Any advice on how to do it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're syncing between Ubuntu and Android such that you are getting duplicates, but I found from a post elsewhere here that you can email the vcf file to yourself and in Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 4 (OTA-13) when you tap on the attachment, it will ask which app you want to open it with, and when you select Contacts, they will be imported! (It's beyond me why the import capability is present but not exposed in the UI...)

Answer (score 0):

1/ what is the connection to Ubuntu? seems you are trying to sync between 2 phones.

2/ to export from android, search the google store for "contact export". this will save your contacts in csv, vfcf, pdf to your phone.  you then copy from phone to pc via any means you prefer: wifi, blue, usb.